# Composite band through Batch processing using Sentinal 2 data in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, error-000732, for-loop, if-else, environment-variable

As we know sentinel satellite data have many sub folder. I want to create composite band of each datasets with the band 2, band 3, band 4, band 8 which are located in one folder(10m) and band 11, band 12 which are located in other folder(20m).I am making a arcpy code for that but code was not run correctly. Here is the code

```
import arcpy, os

basepath = "L:\Arcpy\Data\Satellite_image_raw\New folder"

endswith = ("_B02_10m.jp2", "_B03_10m.jp2", "_B04_10m.jp2", "_B08_10m.jp2", "_B11_20m.jp2", "_B12_20m.jp2")

output = "L:\Arcpy\Data\Layer_stack"

rasterlist = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(basepath):
    for rasterlayer in files:
        if rasterlayer.endswith(endswith):
           #print(os.path.join(root, rasterlayer))
           rasterlist.append(rasterlayer)
           print "image:" + str(rasterlist)
name = os.path.join(output, rasterlist[1].split("_")[0] + ".img")
arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rasterlist, name)
print(rasterlist)
```

I was trying these code but output is not created. It gave this error:

```
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', n 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B12_20m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B12_20m.jp2', 'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B12_20m.jp2', 'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2']
 image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B12_20m.jp2', 'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2']
image:['T45QVD_20210104T044201_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B08_10m.jp2', 'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T45QVD_20210104T044201_B12_20m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2', 'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B11_20m.jp2', 
'T44QRJ_20210102T045209_B12_20m.jp2', 'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B02_10m.jp2', 
'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B03_10m.jp2', 'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B04_10m.jp2', 
'T45QUD_20210102T045209_B08_10m.jp2']

 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "L:\Arcpy\Py_script\composite_band_script_1.py", line 35, in <module>
 arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rasterlist, name)
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", 
 line 13647, in CompositeBands
 raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Rasters:
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: Anyone have this solution?

Answer (score 1):

A few lines of code you should take another look at:

1. Check the input parameters for file.endswith(). I suspect it expects a single string as input, rather than a tuple with many strings.
2. The first parameter of [arcpy.CompositeBands_managment()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/composite-bands.htm) expects all the rasters you are joining as a list, not one raster at a time. I would recommend at this point in the for loops you add the names to a list, and then after the for loops are finished run arcpy.CompositeBands_managment(input_list, newname).
3. Check if name = os.path.join() is outputting what you want it to. Specifically, whether file[1] gives you what you think it does.

Comment: 1. When I am print these line: print(os.path.join(root, file)) without re-meaning code, It is gave selected bands from every folder.  2. I am using tuple because endswith() doesn't except list.  3. Data set is not opneing that's why name = os.path.join() is not working.

Comment: Your arcpy command is expecting a list of strings (file paths - directories and filenames) for its first parameter, and the second parameter should be a single string of the output file path. The error says that it cannot open the input datasets which means there is a problem with file. "file" is also a builtin in python, so if you are trying to use it as a variable name (as "for file in files" would suggest) this may cause problems.

Comment: As per you instruction I was making a empty list and assign the variable which have selected bands and for second parameter I would converted the list into string. Also I would change "file" to rasterlayer. But still I  am getting the same error.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain how you've changed your code. That will help other potential answerers see what you are currently working with.

Comment: I have done changes in above code for your reference.

Comment: This still comes back to point 2 in my answer - the first parameter of arcpy.CompositeBands_management() is still a single raster. Instead of "rasterlist = rasterlayer" use "rasterlist.append(rasterlayer)" and then use arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rasterlist, name).

Comment: I have made some changes as per your instruction in above code and this time it's gave above error. Also I have a question , when rasterlayer is assign to rasterlist then all selected bands from every folder store in rasterlist. When we run composite band with rasterlist then all selected bands combine in one raster. Am I right?

Comment: If it's like that only then I don't want to composite all band together. I want composite band for each dataset. if there are 14 dataset then I want 14 individual composite bands.

Comment: Rasterlayer should only be appended to rasterlist if it has the correct ending. All rasters/bands inputted arcpy.CompositeBands_management() will be merged together into one multi-band raster, so you want to be calling this function once per dataset (i.e. you need to loop through the datasets one at a time). You may also need to check if .jp2 is a file format Esri can work with. The new error you are getting suggests that it is not a valid file format for this function.

Comment: .jp2 file format are supported in Esri because when I was run composite band manually in Arcmap its ruining correctly.  (i.e. you need to loop through the datasets one at a time). Can you guide me on this.

Comment: I've given all the guidance I have on this problem - make sure rasterlist and name contain what you think they do (i.e. double check with print statements), and confirm that this is valid input for arcpy.CompositeBands_management()

Comment: I want one dataset go through rasterlist in arcpy.CompositeBands_management() at a time. For name I want only tile name like T45QVD.img. Also I added getting error in above code for you reference. I am very sure that arcpy.CompositeBands_management() tool supported .jp2 file format.

Comment: You need to find a way to walk the directories so that you can run arcpy.CompositeBands_management() once per dataset, and reset rasterlist before walking through each dataset. I don't know how Sentinel directories are structured.

Comment: This is how Sentinel directories are structured- S2A_MSIL2A_20210104T044201_N0214_R033_T45QVD_20210104T063322.SAFE is the main folder. There are five sub folder like AUX_DATA, DATASTRIP, GRANULE, HTML, and rep_info. GRANULE sub folder have satellite tile folder like L2A_T45QVD_A028916_20210104T044202. This folder also have three sub folder like AUX_DATA, IMG_DATA and QI_DATA. From those three sub folder IMG_DATA have all bands which are placed into again three sub folder. Those are 10m, 20m and 60m.